# OpenVPN connecting two networks with the same local segments

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have two networks in 2 different physical locations (A, B).
Both have lots of things sitting on the 192.168.1.x segment.
I wish to connect to Network A from a Windows PC on Network B and "see" all the resources on Network A.

If required, I am happy to lose sight of all resources on Network B, although the best solution of all would be to translate/reroute Network A addresses from 192.168.1.x to something else like 10.10.1.x and let me access both sets of resources.

I have OpenVPN and PPTP servers available (provided by my Asus Merlin Router) and I have the latest OpenVPN client for Windows.

There must be a way for my PC on Network B, to effectively join Network A.
But all the basic OpenVPN servers and clients configs I have tried, create a commingled, overlapping mish-mash of devices from both Networks!

Ideas?

UPDATE:

Partial success. Local ip addresses are cut off....but I still seem to have access to all my local PC's. And, I have ip access to devices on the remote network (but not remote PC's)!
The trick was to redirect all local traffic to the remote:
`redirect-gateway def1 block-local`.

Half way there.

Comment: Renumber one of your networks  There is no good way that is going to have a site-to-site VPN between two networks using the same subnet.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option. As I said I could live with dropping all local resource access when connected to the VPN (but can;t figure out how to do that). I could also use NAT on specific resources (if I could figure out how to do that!)

Comment: One other option.  Give up on IPv4 connectivity between the two networks.  Setup and route IPv6 on both.  You probably don't have IPv6 now, and you could generate  unique locate addresses for each site.  https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4193

Comment: Thre must be some way to have either the local or remote network to masquerade as a different segment. i.e. an addresses of 192.168.1.100 becomes 10.10.1.100 and so on. If the address is AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD, AAA and BBB get changed on any traffic to or from one of the networks.

Comment: Article covering similar scenario: https://help.endian.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012029614-OpenVPN-How-to-connect-two-sites-with-same-network-address